# PHP Pagination based on some condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pagination

I'm new to PHP. I have android app which displays wallpapers.The following PHP script returns the data from Most recent to Most old in pagination. It is working fine but the problem is it always starts collecting rows from the end no matter what the condition is. For example if i want to retrieve the Wallpapers with category ABSTRACT from most recent to most old it starts with the last id and ignore the category and give incorrect result.
Here is what i want.

1. Get wallpapers based on some category
2. Store the result in some array
3. Calculate from and to variable from that array in give page number
4. Send back the result

i hope you guys have understood what i really want to do. Please help me.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('server', 'abc', '123', 'Walls');

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$page_number = $_POST["page_number"];
$item_count = 40;


$r = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from wallpaper_info order by id desc 
limit 1;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$total = $row[0];


$page_limit = ($total/$item_count) - $page_number; 

$from = $page_limit * $item_count - ($item_count - 1);
$to = $page_limit * $item_count;

$response = array();
$status = array();

if($page_limit <= 0){

array_push($response,array('status'=>'end'));
echo json_encode($response);

}else{

array_push($response,array('status'=>'ok'));

//Working fine
$mysql_query = "select * from wallpaper_info where id BETWEEN $from AND $to 
order by id desc;";
//Not working
$mysql_query = "select * from wallpaper_info where id BETWEEN $from AND $to 
and category = 'Abstract' order by id desc;";

$results = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_query);

$wallpapers = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){

array_push($wallpapers,
array(

'id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'category'=>$row[2],'thumb_url'=>$row[3],'img_ 
 url'=>$row[4],'size'=>$row[5],'downloads'=>$row[6],'views'=>$row[7]

));
}

array_push($response,array('wallpapers'=>$wallpapers));
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: why do you filter by ids?

Comment: @LeoTahk because i want to fetch data by most recent to most old. if you have other method or suggestion in mind please tell me.

Comment: for pagination you can use SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: for old / new its ORDER BY time_column DESC

Comment: @LeoTahk Will this query work? "select * from wallpaper_info where category = 'Abstract' limit 10 offset 0 order by id desc;"

Comment: it should, you can write queries in seperate lines, easier to read and fix, sec ill try to answer with a query

Comment: @LeoTahk Thank you so much for your help. i'm going to try this method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$mysql_query = "SELECT * FROM `wallpaper_info`
                WHERE category = 'Abstract'
                ORDER BY id DESC
                LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
                 ";
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp has good examples

for page number you can try something like:

```
<?php
$pagesize = 10;//LIMIT
$offset = 0;//OFFSET

//pdo query example.. 
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();"
$totall_rows = $conn->query($sql)->fetchColumn(0);

$calc_pages = ceil($totall_rows / $pagesize);
$last_row_number = $pagesize + $offset - 1;

if ($last_row_number >= $totall_rows)
     $last_row_number = $totall_rows - 1;
if ($totall_rows > 0)
     $current_page = ceil(( $calc_pages * ($offset + 1)) / $totall_rows );
?>
<form method="GET" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="">
Page: 
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo "< ";echo($current_page - 1);?>">
<?php echo "<b>$current_page</b>/$calc_pages"; ?>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo($current_page + 1); echo " >";?>">
</form>
<?php
```

didnt test it, tell if not working

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot . This method is super easier. I don't know why i was overthinking that much. :D

Comment: soz if too short answer, whole pagination needs lots of calc of maximum allowed, minimum allowed etc, + you need a safer sql queries with parameter bindings